# Create new ContentVersion with ContentDocumentLink to non-user only

Tags: contentversion, contentdocumentlink

Every time I create a new `ContentVersion` without `ContentDocumentId` it automatically creates a `ContentDocumentLink` that is linked to the user. I just want it to link to an Opportunity so I'm not sure if this default is of use for my use case. But I couldn't find any further information on this behavior either. Can I suppress the creation? Can I delete it afterwards? Can I set the linked record beforehand? Or is this link actually necessary or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) connects a `ContentDocumentId` with a custom or standard object like Opportunity through the `LinkedEntityId`  field.  You'll have to fill in other fields like for visibility, but creating a `ContentDocumentLink` record should do the trick.

I believe creating `ContentVersion` will auto-create the related `ContentDocument` record, which houses the `ContentDocumentId`.  See [this diagram](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm) to wrap your head around the Content objects and also the [ContentNote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm) ERD diagram.

Comment: Nowadays I think this happens so the `ContentVersion` cannot get lost - that's why the system is at least linking it to the user. All of this is not fully answering my initial question but I guess it's as close as it gets.